# What is the ("") for in something like a assignment statement?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

So this is for my Java 1 class. And I'm reading the chapter on Inheritance and Interfaces. This is section "Implementing Subclasses". And there is a piece of code with a feature I don't understand. Basically the part I'm reading is describing how to implement methods. Honestly I don't even know how to say this but can someone explain the point to the empty double quotes on the second line?

```
// Converts choices.size() to string
String choiceString = "" + choices.size();
setAnser (choiceString);
```

Comment: It's a trick we use to invoke a string conversion.  An integer won't automatically convert to a string, but java knows how to build strings.

Comment: Adding to the other answers, if you wonder whether there's another way without using a slightly dubious trick, there is. You could also use `String choiceString = String.valueOf(choices.size());`

Comment: It's a dirty way to change any type into a String.

Answer (score 5):

It's a trick to convert `choices.size()` (an int) to a String, using the String concatenation operator, `+`. To quote the [spec on the String concatenation operator, +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
> conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
> string at run time.

So, in your example, this is a trick to force the integer returned by `choices.size()` to be converted to a string. Then an empty string is prepended, with the final result of a string.

Another, more readable way to do this would be `String.valueOf(choices.size())`.

Comment: Ok so basically the quotes sort of work like a cast assignment, like when you want to turn a type double into type int, or something like that?

Comment: Yes but not the quotes, the + operator.